# Shadowed name in TypeScript and React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, tslint

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript and React-Redux.

I connected my component using connect:

```
import { addTodo } from "../../redux/actions";

export interface Props {
  addTodo: (todo: Todo) => void;
}

// ... component code
  handleAdd = (todo: Todo) => {
    const { addTodo, ... } = this.props; // ... = more destructuring
    // some code ... eventually:
    addTodo(todo);
  } 

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addTodo }
)(MyComponent);
```

The problem is now, that TSLint complains about a shadowed variable:

```
[tslint] Shadowed name: 'addTodo'
```

This feels like a mistake from TypeScript not recognizing React-Redux' functionality. I mean it's taught in the Redux docs to map dispatch to props this way.

Am I doing something wrong? Or do you have to do this differently when using TypeScript?

Comment: You have imported `addTodo` and destructured the same variable from `this.props`. This is clear case of shadowing, you can change name of either to make this go away

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Yeah true, thank you. Mind posting this as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I am facing basically the same problem using JS and ESLint with Airbnb's style guide. This style guides forbids both: not destructuring `props` *and* shadowing variable names, so I feel like I have to violate either one rule or the other. What's the official way of dealing with this. I think you should re-open the question, @J.Hesters. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of TSLint [`no-shadow` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow). It allows to avoid mistakes that result from unintentionally shadowed variables. And it requires to provide workarounds for variables that could be safely shadowed.

Here `addTodo` import is shadowed by `addTodo` prop. It seems this was intentional, the rule is an obstacle in this case.

Such problems with `no-shadow` can be avoided by enforcing a style where objects aren't destructured if variables may become ambiguous. This allows to resolve common problems with similarly named properties, e.g. in `props` and `state` objects. This also can improve the readability in some places because no backtracking is needed, while other places may become more verbose:

```
import * as actions from "../../redux/actions";

// ... component code
  handleAdd = (todo: Todo) => {
    const { props } = this;
    // some code ... eventually:
    props.addTodo(todo);
  } 

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addTodo: actions.addTodo }
)(MyComponent);
```

For multiple action creators as props, some `pick` implementation could be used instead of `{ addTodo: actions.addTodo }`.

This style may be in conflict with ESLint [`prefer-destructuring` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring).